# OO design and Initializing Static members in Asbtract Super class

Tags: java, inheritance, concurrency, static

There are 7-8 class (implements callable) which have some similar behaviour i.e. these have some similar functions with similar implementations. And also all of these makes use of a HashMap (only for reading purpose) which is same for all these classes.
So I decided to make a abstract superclass containing all the similar methods plus this hashMap as a static member.
And I will be making subclasses for these 7-8 callable classes (hence those will also be callable by inheritance), so that performance of app can be improved.

Now I have 3 queries :

1.) Is there any flaw in this design and can I even further improve it ?

2.) Can there occur any concurrency issues as it's a three level hierarchy with callable classes at bottom two levels?

3.) Is initializing static member(hashmap) inside static block wrong ? As my boss is obsessively against using static members and blocks. So what possible problems can occur if I initialize this map inside static block ?

```
public abstract class AbSuper {
private static HashMap hmap; 
private static CompletionService<String> service;
private static int maxThreads = 10;

static{
    initializeMap();
}
 public static void initializeMap(){
     //load from file
 }

public HashMap getmap(){
    return hmap;
}

public void commonMethodOne(){
    //do something
}

public static CompletionService<String> getService(){
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreads);
    service = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executor);
    return service;
}
```

}

```
public class CallableOne extends AbSuper implements Callable<String>{

private List<String[]> taskList;
protected HashMap resultMap;

public List<String[]> getTaskList(){
    return taskList;
}

public String call(){

    for(String[] task : getTaskList()){
        getService().submit(new SubCallableOne(task));
    }

    return "done with Callable One";
}
```

}

```
public class SubCallableOne extends CallableOne {

String[] task;

public SubCallableOne(String[] task) {
    this.task = task;
}

public String call(){
    //do what you are suppose to do
    //and then access and populate "resultMap" fom superclass
    return "done with subCallableOne";
}
```

}

There will be 7-8 CallableOne/two/three and thier corresponding SubCallableOne/two/three.

Comment: Can you please provide some code relevant to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

1) Do you really need to use static members? If so, maybe you should encapsulate that in a separate class and use it through encapsulation instead of inheritance. I'd still keep a superclass with the common methods.

But in any case, your current code has issues. Namely:

- You are exposing the map via the public method `AbSuper.getMap` and it is mutable. Any code could add, delete or overwrite entries. Should it really be public? It looks like only subclasses are using it. If so, you could make it protected and return them a read only map, or a copy, or create a protected function `readFromMap(key)` instead.
- Same for the `AbSuper.getService` method: it is public and static. Any code in any class could submit tasks or shutdown it. Except that you are creating a new executor each time. This is probably a bug, as each call to  `getService` will override the `service` variable. Looks like you were trying to implement a singleton here but failed.

2) Callable classes might be the ones at the bottom, but you are exposing functionality in the base class to every other class in your program due to public static methods, and to anyone holding an instance due to public methods. And even if these methods didn't exist, the fact that all your instances use a shared map and executor service could result in accidental side effects. Execution order of submitted tasks, for instance.

3) It is not wrong per se, but statics are well known code smells. It makes classes hard to test. And cannot be overriden. In pure OO design there should be no need for statics. In your case, the map will be initialized the first time the class is loaded, so any call to `AbSuper.getMap` will get the map populated. But there are two problems with your map. The first one is that this is usually no place for long operations like populating a map from file. You should make long operations explicit, don't hide them in constructors or static initializers. The second is that the map is mutable.